# how to add some information when forwarding to a static page in java?

Tags: javascript, java, http

I'm doing a http forward in Java, and I want to pass some extra parameters to a static page "demo.html", so I tried this:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("demo.html?para=123").forward(request, response);
```

But the javascript function inside "demo.html" cannot get the parameter back. When I use:

```
window.location.search.substring(1)
```

I only got parameters in the before query.

How should I do to trace back "para = 123" in "demo.html" ?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://gomakethings.com/getting-all-query-string-values-from-a-url-with-vanilla-js/)

Comment: The problem is, "demo.html" is displayed by a http forward, so the javascript inside only see the url before the forward, it does not even know the response comes from "demo.html"

Answer (score 0):

Found an alternative way: use cookies.

Any better solution?